# Running 2 versions of three.js

Tags: three.js

I have version 77 running my home page and want to make some updates. I can't seem to figure out how to upgrade from 77 to 100 (latest version). Is it possible to use both versions on the same page?

The code I'm using to pull in the latest version locally:

```
<script src="/static/js/three77.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: Looks like you've missed the link or the code itself. Have a look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r99--r100).

Comment: Yep, I see my code was stripped out. It was a basic script code containing three77.js.  It looks like I would need to spend more time going through ALL notes from 77 to 100 in the migration guide. I gave up after 4 hours.  If it's my only option, I'd just hire someone.

Would it be crazy to have three77.js loaded with the functions underneath, then load three100.js with those functions underneath? Perhaps organized in Divs?

Comment: If you're looking for help, then you also can post the question on the forum: https://discourse.threejs.org :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in time someone will prove this wrong with a better answer, but *no, there is no good way to run multiple versions of three.js on a single page*.

Often, a good workaround around is keeping the old three.js implementation on a separate page and displaying that within an iframe. Iframes are not hip, but very functional that way :-).